# Remove bibliography from beamer template

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I'm doing a presentation using the following beamer template:

```
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
```

I have a file that has my bibliography. I include it has:

```
\begin{frame}{References}
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

The problem is that this adds the bibliography to the left side of the template.

[image: Problem]

I want to remove/hide the bibliography from the template, but keep the slide.

I tried to do something like:

```
\begin{frame}{References}
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography*{bib}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

The main code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\tikzstyle{block}=[draw opacity=0.7,line width=1.4cm]

\title{Presentation} 
\author{}
\today

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}

\frame{\maketitle} 

\begin{frame}{Contents}
    \vspace{-1.20cm}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\include{Objective}
\include{References}

\end{document}

Objective:

\section{Objective}
\begin{frame}{Objective}
\vspace{-1.80cm}
\begin{center}
Presentation
\end{center}
\end{frame}
```

References:

```
\begin{frame}{References}
\vspace{-0.50cm}
\begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
```

As you can see, I don't have a section in references, but it is still appearing in the template.

Comment: You could try to add something like `\let\chapter\relax` (or better `\renewcommand{\chapter}[1]{}` just before the `\bibliography` to ovverride the complete chapter command, but this might destroy the slide title as well...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{..}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I cannot reproduce your problem  with the snippets you provided.

Comment: You see `References` in headline because you've used `\section{References}` in your presentation. Comment out this line and it will desappear from headline. What is shown in `beamer` table of contents is declared with sectioning commands and not with `frames`.